# How to switch to Depth-Based render mode in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I moved my project from Unity 4 to Unity 5, and since then, every time I make a build for iOS or Android, Unity throws following error:

How do I permanently switch to Depth-Based mode, so it never asks again?

[image: Unity 5 compatibility error]

> With Unity 5 is recommended to switch to Depth-Based render mode or Legacy mode with atlases only. Please see Unity 5 Compatibility docmentation page for more information. Do you want to switch to Depth-Based mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Mad Level Manager, a 3rd party lib from the asset store what I used, throwed up this error from code. Overwritten

```
bool sw = EditorUtility.DisplayDialog(
        "Unity 5 Compatibility", "With Unity 5 .......", "Yes (Recommended)", "No");
if (sw) {
    renderMode = RenderMode.DepthBased;
}
```

to

```
renderMode = RenderMode.DepthBased;
```